# Call to referenced controller works in ajax but not with parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, parameters, asp.net-ajax

I have an ASP MVC application where, in the project, I reference to another ASP MVC application. In the referenced application, I have a controller that looks something like this:

```
public class FreddyController : Controller {
    public string Boo( ) {
        return "Eek!";
    }
}
```

While running the main application, I can call the referenced controller and it gives me back an "Eek!"

And, when I attempt that same call in Ajax, using this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Freddy/Boo",
    asynch: false,
    cache: false,
    type: "get",
    error: function (msg) { alert(msg); },
    complete: function (xhr, status) { }
});
```

It works fine too, but when I change it to add a parameter, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Freddy/Boo",
    asynch: false,
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    type: "get",
    data: { resp: 'Eek!' },
    error: function (msg) { alert("Doh!"); },
    success: function (data) { alert(data); },
    complete: function (xhr, status) { alert("Phew...") }
});
```

And the referenced controller to this:

```
public string Boo(string resp) { ...
```

It fails and the error function gets called... Not sure why. Am I missing anything obvious here?

Comment: open your browser console and inspect the actual requests for clues

Comment: is there a reason why the first call is a post and the second one is a get?

Comment: Yes. A mistake on my part. :) Good eyes. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I found the answer to why this is failing. Only problem is, that answer begs more questions from me. I will post that question elsewhere, but in the meantime, for whatever reason, this only works if I have a preventDefault somewhere in the javascript...